# Chrome Print - remove URL from footer but keep page number?

Tags: html, css, printing

I am designing a web page that needs to be printed out. When I used Chrome to print it, the URL gets into the footer, together with the page number. Is there a way for me to remove the URL from the footer BUT KEEP the page number?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to do that in Chrome, though it has been requested before:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/3KYcXfRIQ74

As far as I can tell, the only choice is on or off.

Firefox has quite a bit of flexibility for headers and footers when printing, providing a way to specify what appears in 6 different locations: top/bottom, left/center/right.

Comment: thanks for your response. A bit disappointed about google only able to support this. I guess I will go with firefox.