# Chrome print preview disable only link location in footer and header

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, header

I'm using Chrome print preview for printing and I want to display header and footer to have number of pages but I don't want to display link location in header and footer, for example: http://localhost/test/test.php. And also not to show date at header of print pages.
I was searching everywhere but only get :

```
@page
{margin:0px;
}
```

But this code not display number of pages.
I tried this code  but didn't work:

```
  @media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that `http://localhost/test/test.php` isn't accessible, because it is a link to your own local computer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Print - remove URL from footer but keep page number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740382/chrome-print-remove-url-from-footer-but-keep-page-number)